# Custom ID ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Good night people,

I'm using rails with a ready-made database running in another (remote) application, but in the ActiveAdmin gem at the time of listing, for example, clients, as the client has relationship in a transaction, gem automatically fetches the Transaction by the standard already defined by the rails (id), but the field name is with a different field primary key (Transaction_Number).

[this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt9et.png)

I would like you to help me!